# Animate Pseudo-Class with @keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pseudo-class

I have the following code:

```css
.link {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 3px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%
}

.link:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Some Random Link</a>
```

I have a simple Animation when I hover over my Link. Basically the Underline slides out to the right, when I hover over the element and slides in from the left when I leave the element.

What I want to have is, that it plays the whole Animation when I'm hovering over the Element. I tried creating an Animation with @keyframes but couldn't get it work, because I don't know how to animate only the Pseudo-Class ::after and not the whole element.

Here's also a JSFiddle to better explain what I'm trying to do: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Florian_W7/shyx3q7k/)

Comment: check the second snippet of the accepted answer

Comment: thanks for showing me that, but it's not exactly how I want it. the underline should be there from the beginning.

Comment: please reopen the question as it is not resolved, and currently I'm not able to comment on other questions!

Comment: I have updated the accepted answer. You can obtain any kind of animation, you simply need to understand how it works and how to adjust the values

Comment: alright, thanks a lot!